# Método SQL para login

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

Tenho o seguinte esquema:

```
JdbcRowSet myrs = new JdbcRowSetImpl();

myrs.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:9999/teste");
myrs.setUsername("postgres");
myrs.setPassword("");
myrs.setCommand("select count (*) from pessoas where cpf = '12345'");
myrs.execute();

ResultSetMetaData md = myrs.getMetaData();
String columncount = //Exemplo: getColumnName(1);

if ( columncount == 12345){
    return ("existe");  
} if ( columncount != 12345){
    return ("inexiste");
}
```

Alguém sabe o método que se aplicaria no lugar do //Exemplo para capturar o conteúdo da coluna "cpf" para fins de confirmação da existência do cpf "12345"?

Answer (score 3):

Já tentou `myrs.getString(1)`? Devia funcionar.
Ah, e se `columnCount` é String, a expressão `columnCount == 12345` e a `!=` vão falhar.
Esse post parece usar essa solução, talvez te seja útil
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367828/how-can-i-get-different-datatypes-from-resultsetmetadata-in-java

Comment: Olá, @bupereira. Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Realmente o `getString` é uma saída. Provavelmente o uso do `ResultSetMetaData` é apenas um equívoco. Entretanto, como a query retorna a contagem de registros, acho que o melhor seria usar o `getInt` para atribuir numa variável inteira e no `if` verificar se mais de um registro: `if (count > 0)`.

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas, mas não está funcionando >.<

Comment: Você recebe algum erro?

Comment: Postei o erro como resposta pra ficar melhor de ler, segue abaixo:

Comment: Consegui! fiz o seguinte: JdbcRowSet myrs = new JdbcRowSetImpl();
   
   myrs.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:9999/teste");
   myrs.setUsername("postgres");
   myrs.setPassword("");
   myrs.setCommand("select * from pessoas");
   myrs.execute();
    
    while (myrs.next()) {
     System.out.println(myrs.getString(1));
     }

Comment: Show de bola! Só marca lá como resolvido e vamos pra próxima!